# Display currency format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display some currency with the Euro symbol. It seems I am doing something wrong because it is not working. This is my code:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:N}")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

This is how it is curently displayed: 9.9900.

This is how I would like it to be displayed : €9.99

What am I doing wrong and how can I correct it?

Comment: add this line in web.config : `<globalization uiCulture="fr-FR" culture="fr-FR" />` and try with Ben Robinson answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the currency formatter e.g.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:C}")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```